# How to call readings from one script that reads a sensor to be used by another script that controls servos

Tags: python, sensor, python-3

I'm trying to use the readings of the accelerometer of an IMU MPU9250 to control servos. For that I created (with help of resources online) a script(IMUmodule) that reads the IMU and spits out acceleration of X = AccXangle and Y = AccYangle.

If I run the IMU script I can print X and Y no problem. X and Y are updated every 0.1 seconds.

But if I create another script, that Imports the IMUmodule and try to print the X and Y values either hangs or says that IMUmodlue has no attribute called AccXangle. (which im certain it has)

Here the code that spits out X and Y, otherwise known as IMUmodule.py:

```
from mpu9250_jmdev.registers import *
from mpu9250_jmdev.mpu_9250 import MPU9250
import sys
import time
import math
# import IMU
import datetime
import os

mpu = MPU9250(
    address_ak=AK8963_ADDRESS, 
    address_mpu_master=MPU9050_ADDRESS_68, # In 0x68 Address
    address_mpu_slave=None, 
    bus=1, 
    gfs=GFS_2000, 
    afs=AFS_8G, 
    mfs=AK8963_BIT_16, 
    mode=AK8963_MODE_C100HZ)

mpu.calibrate()
mpu.configure()



# If the IMU is upside down (Skull logo facing up), change this value to 1
IMU_UPSIDE_DOWN = 0


RAD_TO_DEG = 57.29578
M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846
G_GAIN = 0.070          # [deg/s/LSB]  If you change the dps for gyro, you need to update this value accordingly
AA =  0.40              # Complementary filter constant
MAG_LPF_FACTOR = 0.4    # Low pass filter constant magnetometer
ACC_LPF_FACTOR = 0.4    # Low pass filter constant for accelerometer
ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE = 9         # Median filter table size for accelerometer. Higher = smoother but a longer delay
MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE = 9         # Median filter table size for magnetometer. Higher = smoother but a longer delay



################# Compass Calibration values ############
# Use calibrateBerryIMU.py to get calibration values
# Calibrating the compass isnt mandatory, however a calibrated
# compass will result in a more accurate heading value.

magXmin =  0
magYmin =  0
magZmin =  0
magXmax =  0
magYmax =  0
magZmax =  0


'''
Here is an example:
magXmin =  -1748
magYmin =  -1025
magZmin =  -1876
magXmax =  959
magYmax =  1651
magZmax =  708
Dont use the above values, these are just an example.
'''



#Kalman filter variables
Q_angle = 0.02
Q_gyro = 0.0015
R_angle = 0.005
y_bias = 0.0
x_bias = 0.0
XP_00 = 0.0
XP_01 = 0.0
XP_10 = 0.0
XP_11 = 0.0
YP_00 = 0.0
YP_01 = 0.0
YP_10 = 0.0
YP_11 = 0.0
KFangleX = 0.0
KFangleY = 0.0



def kalmanFilterY ( accAngle, gyroRate, DT):
    y=0.0
    S=0.0

    global KFangleY
    global Q_angle
    global Q_gyro
    global y_bias
    global YP_00
    global YP_01
    global YP_10
    global YP_11

    KFangleY = KFangleY + DT * (gyroRate - y_bias)

    YP_00 = YP_00 + ( - DT * (YP_10 + YP_01) + Q_angle * DT )
    YP_01 = YP_01 + ( - DT * YP_11 )
    YP_10 = YP_10 + ( - DT * YP_11 )
    YP_11 = YP_11 + ( + Q_gyro * DT )

    y = accAngle - KFangleY
    S = YP_00 + R_angle
    K_0 = YP_00 / S
    K_1 = YP_10 / S

    KFangleY = KFangleY + ( K_0 * y )
    y_bias = y_bias + ( K_1 * y )

    YP_00 = YP_00 - ( K_0 * YP_00 )
    YP_01 = YP_01 - ( K_0 * YP_01 )
    YP_10 = YP_10 - ( K_1 * YP_00 )
    YP_11 = YP_11 - ( K_1 * YP_01 )

    return KFangleY

def kalmanFilterX ( accAngle, gyroRate, DT):
    x=0.0
    S=0.0

    global KFangleX
    global Q_angle
    global Q_gyro
    global x_bias
    global XP_00
    global XP_01
    global XP_10
    global XP_11


    KFangleX = KFangleX + DT * (gyroRate - x_bias)

    XP_00 = XP_00 + ( - DT * (XP_10 + XP_01) + Q_angle * DT )
    XP_01 = XP_01 + ( - DT * XP_11 )
    XP_10 = XP_10 + ( - DT * XP_11 )
    XP_11 = XP_11 + ( + Q_gyro * DT )

    x = accAngle - KFangleX
    S = XP_00 + R_angle
    K_0 = XP_00 / S
    K_1 = XP_10 / S

    KFangleX = KFangleX + ( K_0 * x )
    x_bias = x_bias + ( K_1 * x )

    XP_00 = XP_00 - ( K_0 * XP_00 )
    XP_01 = XP_01 - ( K_0 * XP_01 )
    XP_10 = XP_10 - ( K_1 * XP_00 )
    XP_11 = XP_11 - ( K_1 * XP_01 )

    return KFangleX


gyroXangle = 0.0
gyroYangle = 0.0
gyroZangle = 0.0
CFangleX = 0.0
CFangleY = 0.0
CFangleXFiltered = 0.0
CFangleYFiltered = 0.0
kalmanX = 0.0
kalmanY = 0.0
oldXMagRawValue = 0
oldYMagRawValue = 0
oldZMagRawValue = 0
oldXAccRawValue = 0
oldYAccRawValue = 0
oldZAccRawValue = 0

a = datetime.datetime.now()



#Setup the tables for the mdeian filter. Fill them all with '1' so we dont get devide by zero error
acc_medianTable1X = [1] * ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE
acc_medianTable1Y = [1] * ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE
acc_medianTable1Z = [1] * ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE
acc_medianTable2X = [1] * ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE
acc_medianTable2Y = [1] * ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE
acc_medianTable2Z = [1] * ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE
mag_medianTable1X = [1] * MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE
mag_medianTable1Y = [1] * MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE
mag_medianTable1Z = [1] * MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE
mag_medianTable2X = [1] * MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE
mag_medianTable2Y = [1] * MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE
mag_medianTable2Z = [1] * MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE

# IMU.detectIMU()     #Detect if BerryIMUv1 or BerryIMUv2 is connected.
# IMU.initIMU()       #Initialise the accelerometer, gyroscope and compass


while True:

    acceleration = mpu.readAccelerometerMaster()
    accelerationX = acceleration[0]
    accelerationY = acceleration[1]
    accelerationZ = acceleration[2]

    rotation = mpu.readGyroscopeMaster()
    rotationX = rotation[0]
    rotationY = rotation[1]
    rotationZ = rotation[2]

    magnetic = mpu.readMagnetometerMaster()
    magneticX = magnetic[0]
    magneticY = magnetic[1]
    magneticZ = magnetic[2]

    #Read the accelerometer,gyroscope and magnetometer values
    ACCx = acceleration[0]#IMU.readACCx()
    ACCy = acceleration[1]#IMU.readACCy()
    ACCz = acceleration[2]#IMU.readACCz()
    GYRx = rotation[0]#IMU.readGYRx()
    GYRy = rotation[1]#IMU.readGYRy()
    GYRz = rotation[2]#IMU.readGYRz()
    MAGx = magnetic[0]#IMU.readMAGx()
    MAGy = magnetic[1]#IMU.readMAGy()
    MAGz = magnetic[2]#IMU.readMAGz()


    #Apply compass calibration
    MAGx -= (magXmin + magXmax) /2
    MAGy -= (magYmin + magYmax) /2
    MAGz -= (magZmin + magZmax) /2


    ##Calculate loop Period(LP). How long between Gyro Reads
    b = datetime.datetime.now() - a
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    LP = b.microseconds/(1000000*1.0)
    outputString = "Loop Time %5.2f " % ( LP )



    ###############################################
    #### Apply low pass filter ####
    ###############################################
    MAGx =  MAGx  * MAG_LPF_FACTOR + oldXMagRawValue*(1 - MAG_LPF_FACTOR);
    MAGy =  MAGy  * MAG_LPF_FACTOR + oldYMagRawValue*(1 - MAG_LPF_FACTOR);
    MAGz =  MAGz  * MAG_LPF_FACTOR + oldZMagRawValue*(1 - MAG_LPF_FACTOR);
    ACCx =  ACCx  * ACC_LPF_FACTOR + oldXAccRawValue*(1 - ACC_LPF_FACTOR);
    ACCy =  ACCy  * ACC_LPF_FACTOR + oldYAccRawValue*(1 - ACC_LPF_FACTOR);
    ACCz =  ACCz  * ACC_LPF_FACTOR + oldZAccRawValue*(1 - ACC_LPF_FACTOR);

    oldXMagRawValue = MAGx
    oldYMagRawValue = MAGy
    oldZMagRawValue = MAGz
    oldXAccRawValue = ACCx
    oldYAccRawValue = ACCy
    oldZAccRawValue = ACCz

    #########################################
    #### Median filter for accelerometer ####
    #########################################
    # cycle the table
    for x in range (ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE-1,0,-1 ):
        acc_medianTable1X[x] = acc_medianTable1X[x-1]
        acc_medianTable1Y[x] = acc_medianTable1Y[x-1]
        acc_medianTable1Z[x] = acc_medianTable1Z[x-1]

    # Insert the lates values
    acc_medianTable1X[0] = ACCx
    acc_medianTable1Y[0] = ACCy
    acc_medianTable1Z[0] = ACCz

    # Copy the tables
    acc_medianTable2X = acc_medianTable1X[:]
    acc_medianTable2Y = acc_medianTable1Y[:]
    acc_medianTable2Z = acc_medianTable1Z[:]

    # Sort table 2
    acc_medianTable2X.sort()
    acc_medianTable2Y.sort()
    acc_medianTable2Z.sort()

    # The middle value is the value we are interested in
    ACCx = acc_medianTable2X[int(ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE/2)];
    ACCy = acc_medianTable2Y[int(ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE/2)];
    ACCz = acc_medianTable2Z[int(ACC_MEDIANTABLESIZE/2)];



    #########################################
    #### Median filter for magnetometer ####
    #########################################
    # cycle the table
    for x in range (MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE-1,0,-1 ):
        mag_medianTable1X[x] = mag_medianTable1X[x-1]
        mag_medianTable1Y[x] = mag_medianTable1Y[x-1]
        mag_medianTable1Z[x] = mag_medianTable1Z[x-1]

    # Insert the latest values
    mag_medianTable1X[0] = MAGx
    mag_medianTable1Y[0] = MAGy
    mag_medianTable1Z[0] = MAGz

    # Copy the tables
    mag_medianTable2X = mag_medianTable1X[:]
    mag_medianTable2Y = mag_medianTable1Y[:]
    mag_medianTable2Z = mag_medianTable1Z[:]

    # Sort table 2
    mag_medianTable2X.sort()
    mag_medianTable2Y.sort()
    mag_medianTable2Z.sort()

    # The middle value is the value we are interested in
    MAGx = mag_medianTable2X[int(MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE/2)];
    MAGy = mag_medianTable2Y[int(MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE/2)];
    MAGz = mag_medianTable2Z[int(MAG_MEDIANTABLESIZE/2)];



    #Convert Gyro raw to degrees per second
    rate_gyr_x =  GYRx * G_GAIN
    rate_gyr_y =  GYRy * G_GAIN
    rate_gyr_z =  GYRz * G_GAIN


    #Calculate the angles from the gyro.
    gyroXangle+=rate_gyr_x*LP
    gyroYangle+=rate_gyr_y*LP
    gyroZangle+=rate_gyr_z*LP

    #Convert Accelerometer values to degrees

#     if not IMU_UPSIDE_DOWN:
#         # If the IMU is up the correct way (Skull logo facing down), use these calculations
#         AccXangle =  (math.atan2(ACCy,ACCz)*RAD_TO_DEG)
#         AccYangle =  (math.atan2(ACCz,ACCx)+M_PI)*RAD_TO_DEG
#     else:
#         #Us these four lines when the IMU is upside down. Skull logo is facing up
#         AccXangle =  (math.atan2(-ACCy,-ACCz)*RAD_TO_DEG)
#         AccYangle =  (math.atan2(-ACCz,-ACCx)+M_PI)*RAD_TO_DEG

#     if not IMU_UPSIDE_DOWN:
#         # If the IMU is up the correct way (Skull logo facing down), use these calculations
    AccXangle =  (math.atan2(ACCy,ACCz)*RAD_TO_DEG)
    AccYangle =  (math.atan2(ACCz,ACCx)+M_PI)*RAD_TO_DEG
#     else:
#         #Us these four lines when the IMU is upside down. Skull logo is facing up
#         AccXangle =  (math.atan2(-ACCy,-ACCz)*RAD_TO_DEG)
#         AccYangle =  (math.atan2(-ACCz,-ACCx)+M_PI)*RAD_TO_DEG



    #Change the rotation value of the accelerometer to -/+ 180 and
    #move the Y axis '0' point to up.  This makes it easier to read.
    if AccYangle > 90:
        AccYangle -= 270.0
    else:
        AccYangle += 90.0



    #Complementary filter used to combine the accelerometer and gyro values.
    CFangleX=AA*(CFangleX+rate_gyr_x*LP) +(1 - AA) * AccXangle
    CFangleY=AA*(CFangleY+rate_gyr_y*LP) +(1 - AA) * AccYangle

    #Kalman filter used to combine the accelerometer and gyro values.
    kalmanY = kalmanFilterY(AccYangle, rate_gyr_y,LP)
    kalmanX = kalmanFilterX(AccXangle, rate_gyr_x,LP)

#     if IMU_UPSIDE_DOWN:
#         MAGy = -MAGy      #If IMU is upside down, this is needed to get correct heading.
    #Calculate heading
    heading = 180 * math.atan2(MAGy,MAGx)/M_PI

    #Only have our heading between 0 and 360
    if heading < 0:
        heading += 360



    ####################################################################
    ###################Tilt compensated heading#########################
    ####################################################################
    #Normalize accelerometer raw values.
#     if not IMU_UPSIDE_DOWN:
#         #Use these two lines when the IMU is up the right way. Skull logo is facing down
#         accXnorm = ACCx/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)
#         accYnorm = ACCy/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)
#     else:
#         #Us these four lines when the IMU is upside down. Skull logo is facing up
#         accXnorm = -ACCx/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)
#         accYnorm = ACCy/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)

#     if not IMU_UPSIDE_DOWN:
#         #Use these two lines when the IMU is up the right way. Skull logo is facing down
    accXnorm = ACCx/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)
    accYnorm = ACCy/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)
#     else:
#         #Us these four lines when the IMU is upside down. Skull logo is facing up
#         accXnorm = -ACCx/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)
#         accYnorm = ACCy/math.sqrt(ACCx * ACCx + ACCy * ACCy + ACCz * ACCz)

    #Calculate pitch and roll

    pitch = math.asin(accXnorm)
    roll = -math.asin(accYnorm/math.cos(pitch))


    #Calculate the new tilt compensated values
    magXcomp = MAGx*math.cos(pitch)+MAGz*math.sin(pitch)

    #The compass and accelerometer are orientated differently on the LSM9DS0 and LSM9DS1 and the Z axis on the compass
    #is also reversed. This needs to be taken into consideration when performing the calculations
#     if(IMU.LSM9DS0):
#         magYcomp = MAGx*math.sin(roll)*math.sin(pitch)+MAGy*math.cos(roll)-MAGz*math.sin(roll)*math.cos(pitch)   #LSM9DS0
#     else:
#         magYcomp = MAGx*math.sin(roll)*math.sin(pitch)+MAGy*math.cos(roll)+MAGz*math.sin(roll)*math.cos(pitch)   #LSM9DS1
    magYcomp = MAGx*math.sin(roll)*math.sin(pitch)+MAGy*math.cos(roll)-MAGz*math.sin(roll)*math.cos(pitch)   #LSM9DS0




        #Calculate tilt compensated heading
    tiltCompensatedHeading = 180 * math.atan2(magYcomp,magXcomp)/M_PI

    if tiltCompensatedHeading < 0:
        tiltCompensatedHeading += 360


        ############################ END ##################################

    print("IMU TEST START", '\n', "Accel in X= ", AccXangle, '\n', "Accel in Y= ", AccYangle, '\n', 'GyroX = ', gyroXangle, '\n', "GyroY = ", gyroYangle, '\n', "GyroZ = ", gyroZangle, '\n', "Heading = ", heading, '\n', 'Compensated Heading = ', '\n', tiltCompensatedHeading, '\n')

#     if 1:                       #Change to '0' to stop showing the angles from the accelerometer
#         outputString += "t# ACCX Angle %5.2f ACCY Angle %5.2f #  " % (AccXangle, AccYangle)
#         
# 
#     if 1:                       #Change to '0' to stop  showing the angles from the gyro
#         outputString +="\t# GRYX Angle %5.2f  GYRY Angle %5.2f  GYRZ Angle %5.2f # " % (gyroXangle,gyroYangle,gyroZangle)
#         
# 
#     if 1:                       #Change to '0' to stop  showing the angles from the complementary filter
#         outputString +="\t# CFangleX Angle %5.2f   CFangleY Angle %5.2f #" % (CFangleX,CFangleY)
#         
# 
#     if 1:                       #Change to '0' to stop  showing the heading
#         outputString +="\t# HEADING %5.2f  tiltCompensatedHeading %5.2f #" % (heading,tiltCompensatedHeading)
#         
# 
#     if 0:                       #Change to '0' to stop  showing the angles from the Kalman filter
#         outputString +="# kalmanX %5.2f   kalmanY %5.2f #" % (kalmanX,kalmanY)
# 
#     print(outputString)

    #slow program down a bit, makes the output more readable
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

As test, i made a test code to make sure i could import x and y:

```
import sys
import IMUmodule

print(IMUmodule.AccXangle)
```

But it says IMUmodlue has no attribute called AccXangle.

Im new to Python and all things RPI so please forgive my ignorance.

Thank you.
Shoutout to OZZMAKER for creating mostly all the code above.

---EDIT---

I'm adding here the code I made to move the servos manually. I want to use the measurements from IMUmodule ( AccXangle, and AccYangle), to create conditions to move the servos.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import curses
import os
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit

kit = ServoKit(channels=16)

# global angle0
# global angle1
# global angle2
# global angle3
angle0 = 90
angle1 = 90
angle2 = 90
angle3 = 90

increment_factor = 2

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(True)

#Set the GPIO port to BCM encoding mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Ignore warning information
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Servo initialization operation
def Servo_init():
#     global angleleft
#     global angleright
    #servo1
    kit.servo[0].angle = 90
    kit.servo[0].actuation_range = 180
    #servo2
    kit.servo[1].angle = 90
    kit.servo[1].actuation_range = 180
    #servo3
    kit.servo[2].angle = 90
    kit.servo[2].actuation_range = 180
    #servo4
    kit.servo[3].angle = 90
    kit.servo[3].actuation_range = 180    
    kit.servo[0].set_pulse_width_range(475, 2550)    
    kit.servo[1].set_pulse_width_range(475, 2550)
    kit.servo[2].set_pulse_width_range(475, 2550)   
    kit.servo[3].set_pulse_width_range(475, 2550)


def center():
    global angle0
    global angle1
    global angle2
    global angle3

    kit.servo[0].angle = 90
    kit.servo[1].angle = 90
    kit.servo[2].angle = 90
    kit.servo[3].angle = 90
    angle0 = 90
    angle1 = 90
    angle2 = 90
    angle3 = 90

    print("Centered")
    return


def rise():#we add degs to raise the platform
    global angle0
    global angle1
    global angle2
    global angle3

    if 0 <= angle0 < 180:
        angle0 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[0].angle = angle0

    if 0 <= angle1 < 180:
        angle1 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[1].angle = 180 - angle1
#         
    if 0 <= angle2 < 180:
        angle2 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[2].angle = angle2
#         
    if 0 <= angle3 < 180:
        angle3 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[3].angle = 180 - angle3

    print(angle0, angle1, angle2, angle3)
    return

def fall():#we substract degrees to lower the platform
    global angle0
    global angle1
    global angle2
    global angle3

    if 0 < angle0 <= 180:
        angle0 -= increment_factor
        kit.servo[0].angle = angle0

    if 0 < angle1 <= 180:
        angle1 -= increment_factor
        kit.servo[1].angle = 180 - angle1
#         
    if 0 < angle2 <= 180:
        angle2 -= increment_factor
        kit.servo[2].angle = angle2
#         
    if 0 < angle3 <= 180:
        angle3 -= increment_factor
        kit.servo[3].angle = 180 - angle3

    print(angle0, angle1, angle2, angle3)
    return


def tilt_left():
    global angle0
    global angle1
    global angle2
    global angle3

    if 0 < angle0 <=180:   #we lift the left track     
        angle0 -= increment_factor        
        kit.servo[0].angle = angle0        
    if 0 < angle2 <=180:        
        angle2 -= increment_factor        
        kit.servo[2].angle = angle2
    if 0 <= angle1 < 180: #we lower the right track
        angle1 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[1].angle = 180 - angle1        
    if 0 <= angle3 < 180: #we lower the right track
        angle3 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[3].angle = 180 - angle3

        print(angle0, angle1, angle2, angle3)
        return

def tilt_right():
    global angle0
    global angle1
    global angle2
    global angle3

    if 0 < angle1 <=180:   #we lift the left track     
        angle1 -= increment_factor        
        kit.servo[1].angle = 180 - angle1        
    if 0 < angle3 <=180:        
        angle3 -= increment_factor        
        kit.servo[3].angle = 180 - angle3
    if 0 <= angle0 < 180: #we lower the right track
        angle0 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[0].angle = angle0        
    if 0 <= angle2 < 180: #we lower the right track
        angle2 += increment_factor
        kit.servo[2].angle = angle2            
        print(angle0, angle1, angle2, angle3)
        return

#def tilt_forward():    

try:

    Servo_init()
    while True:        
        char = screen.getch()
        if char == ord('o'):
            rise()                        

        elif char == ord('l'):            
            fall()

        elif char == ord('k'):                        
            tilt_left()         

        elif char == ord(';'):
            tilt_right()            

        elif char == ord(' '):
           # if 180 > angleleft >= 0 and 180 > angleright >= 0:            
#                 angleleft -= 2
#                 angleright += 2
                angleleft = angleright

                kit.servo[0].angle = angleleft
                kit.servo[1].angle = 180 - angleright
                kit.servo[2].angle = angleleft
                kit.servo[3].angle = 180 - angleright

                print(angleleft, angleright)

        elif char == ord('w'):
            #if 180 > angleleft >= 0 and 180 > angleright >= 0:            
#                 angleleft -= 2
#                 angleright += 2
                kit.servo[0].angle = 0
                kit.servo[1].angle = 180
                kit.servo[2].angle = 0
                kit.servo[3].angle = 180

        elif char == ord('s'):
            #if 180 > angleleft >= 0 and 180 > angleright >= 0:            
#                 angleleft -= 2
#                 angleright += 2
                kit.servo[0].angle = 180
                kit.servo[1].angle = 0
                kit.servo[2].angle = 180
                kit.servo[3].angle = 0
                angleleft = 180
                angleright = 180

                print(angleleft, angleright)

        elif char == ord('r'):
            center()
#             global angle0
#             global angle1
#             global angle2
#             global angle3
#             #if 180 > angleleft >= 0 and 180 > angleright >= 0:            
# #                 angleleft -= 2
# #                 angleright += 2
#             kit.servo[0].angle = 180 - angle0
#             kit.servo[1].angle = 180 - angle1
#             kit.servo[2].angle = 180 - angle2
#             kit.servo[3].angle = 180 - angle3
















finally:
    curses.nocbreak(); screen.keypad(0); curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    GPIO.cleanup()
    kit.servo[0].angle = 90
    kit.servo[1].angle = 90
    kit.servo[2].angle = 90
    kit.servo[3].angle = 90
    kit.servo[4].angle = 90
```

Comment: it is unclear what problem you are facing .... why do you need two scripts? .... why is the "read sensor" and "control servo" not in one script?

Comment: Does my suggestion in the following two-python-script question help? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111447/how-to-run-import-serial-and-import-cv2-in-one-python-file.

Comment: This seems to be a general programming question.

Comment: @jsotola I'm using 2 scripts as means of keeping the code organized and being able to debug in a clear way. I tried today fusing both scripts ( IMUmodule, and the one that controls the servos manually) but it seems to be conflicting, it doesn't show any errors, but the controls are not responding and servos don't move. I imagine it could be a conflict with curses module...

Comment: @tlfong01thank you for replying. As far as I can see, isn't that what im doing in my "test" script? I Import IMUmodule, then i print(IMUmodule.AccXangle). AccXangle is a variable that exists in IMUmodule, so I should be able to call it that way no? thats my issue. Obviously im doing something wrong but i fail to see what.

Comment: @joan. You are mostly right. But since I'm using a sensor that communicates through I2C and I'm also controlling servos, I imagined there could be a conflict of hardware, threading, multiprocessing or something like thats inherent to the RPi of which am unaware of. As I said before I'm new to all this and I figured i'd try my luck here. Thanks for replying.